# Show range according to the number of points in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I need advice.

I have a simple while loop.
And I have a table contestants. Each contestant has a total column [celkem].

These data excerpting the cycle while

And I need that when you have two points as well, so it was always in range (see picture)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/47bp5.png]

The rest of excerpting something like this: $ row ['name']; $ row ['bodycelkem']

My question is, how to use PHP and MySQL dump this range order?

Edit:
[SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a880/1)

(I need auto rank where point in range)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry Im filled SQL with data

Comment: Are you wanting to get the range from the first column in what you posted here? `3. - 4.` etc? I don't get the get question. If so look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html or http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between hard to say what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh no,  I'll try to clarify. I have a mysql database and the data in it. These data echo in document.
I am trying that when the order listed it should be four rows have the same number of points (see img) I want to rank listed 5. - 8. Next would be to 9.
I have echo rank before name.

Comment: Try `WHERE celkem = '87,3' GROUP BY celkem` if that is what you are asking. Or simply `GROUP BY celkem` if otherwise. Please show us your expected results to be 100% certain.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Expected result is this "Pořadí" in image. I need this "Pořadí" auto show near by name ("Jméno"). Group by and where my problem not to solve

Comment: Now I have [SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a880/41/0) 
But I need to (in this case) was 4 x 4, but the range of 4. - 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `Poradi` info does not exist, you need to extrapolate it. You can do this with variables. See my SQL below or in the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86b85/50)

```
SELECT `range`, jmeno, rangeData.celkem FROM `hraci` 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      a1.*, 
      if( range_start = range_end, 
          range_start, CONCAT(range_start,", - ",range_end)
      ) `range` 
    FROM (
      SELECT
        q1.*,
        (@runtot + 1) AS range_start, 
        (@runtot := @runtot + q1.num) range_end
      FROM (
        SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 rank, t1.num, t1.celkem FROM (
          SELECT celkem, count(celkem) num FROM hraci GROUP BY celkem ORDER BY celkem DESC
      ) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
    ) q1, (SELECT @runtot:=0) q2
  ) a1
) rangeData ON hraci.`celkem` = rangeData.`celkem`
```

**How does this work?**

1. Group the 'celkem' values together, descending. Keep an aggregate of how many 'celkem' values are in each group.
2. Add a row count to that data, using variables
3. Using variables again, keep a running total of the group sizes, which will give us the 'range end'. Taking the variable from the last run before incrementing it gives us the 'range start'
4. If the start and end is the same, just use the start. If the start and end is different, display both values
5. We now have the Poradi (range?). We can now proceed to just collect our data as normal, but now we can join the groups onto the names.
6. Neaten all the data up by just selecting the columns we want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hraci;

CREATE TABLE hraci (
  jmeno VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  celkem DOUBLE NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO hraci 
(jmeno, celkem) VALUES 
('Dan', 97.5),
('Adam', 97.2),
('Petr', 90.5),
('Pavel', 90.5),
('Michal', 87.3),
('Jan', 87.3),
('David', 87.3),
('Tomás', 87.3),
('Jarda', 85.2);

SELECT a.celkem
     , a.jmeno
     , CASE WHEN MIN(b.rank)-1 <> a.rank THEN CONCAT(a.rank,' - ',MIN(b.rank) - 1) ELSE a.rank END rank
  FROM 
     ( SELECT celkem
     , jmeno
     , FIND_IN_SET(celkem,celkems) rank
  FROM hraci
 CROSS
  JOIN
     ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( celkem ORDER BY celkem DESC) celkems
         FROM hraci
     ) x
     ) a
LEFT JOIN
     ( SELECT celkem
     , jmeno
     , FIND_IN_SET(celkem,celkems) rank
  FROM hraci
 CROSS
  JOIN
     ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( celkem ORDER BY celkem DESC) celkems
         FROM hraci
     ) y
     ) b
    ON b.rank > a.rank
GROUP BY a.celkem,a.jmeno;

+--------+--------+-------+
| celkem | jmeno  | rank  |
+--------+--------+-------+
|   85.2 | Jarda  | 9     |
|   87.3 | David  | 5 - 8 |
|   87.3 | Jan    | 5 - 8 |
|   87.3 | Michal | 5 - 8 |
|   87.3 | Tomás  | 5 - 8 |
|   90.5 | Pavel  | 3 - 4 |
|   90.5 | Petr   | 3 - 4 |
|   97.2 | Adam   | 2     |
|   97.5 | Dan    | 1     |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a7a5/2